# MYSQL selecting records adjacent/ records that share a key with records that are easy to select

Tags: wordpress

I've got a database of historical records that I'm working on.

In this db, I have a table of officers, a table of service records, a table of report-lines (each reports has many lines, which are transcribed individually).

When a report-line is put into a database, it creates rows in secondary tables for the ship, each officer mentioned, and the locations mentioned.

What I'm trying to do is find out how many other individual officers an officer worked with directly over say 15 years.

I'm pretty new to this, and I'm struggling with self joins. This is going to be in Wordpress, with php/wpdb, and I'm going to be feeding in a key. I would like the self join to:

find all the service records associated with the key I feed in, then find all the service records that have the same record_line_f_key as the first group, and then return those- but not including the ones that have the original officer's key.

I've looked at a couple of tutorials and I just can't get my head around the query structure.

UP to now I've been using nested for loops and I want to rewrite all my code to use joins instead to make the site more efficient.

[image: This is the structure of the table.]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with a bit of help from a friend and w3school

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*,t3.report_date 
FROM officer_service_records t1, officer_service_records t2, reports_list t3
WHERE t1.officer_key = 'sample data'
AND t2.record_line_f_key = t1.record_line_f_key
AND t2.officer_key <> 'sample data'
AND t3.report_key = t2.report_key
```

I've actually modified this to also pull something from yet another table (and only return the unique records